# Merging select consecutive rows in a data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set of the following format

```
    ID 12345
    NAME JohnDoe
    INFO Info about the individual
    INFO Extra info about the individual

    ID 12346
    NAME JaneDoe
    INFO Info about the individual

    ID 12347
    NAME JohnSmith
    INFO Info about the individual
```

Right now I have a data frame that looks like this:

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| ID. | 12345 |
| Name. | JohnDoe |
| Info | Info about the individual |
| Info | Extra info about the individual |
|  |  |
| ID. | 12346 |
| Name. | JaneDoe |
| Info | Info about the individual |
|  |  |
| ID. | 12347 |
| Name. | JohnSmith |
| Info | Info about the individual. |

Where an ID and Name can have one or more associated pieces of information and entire items are separated by a blank row.

And I want to create a table that looks like:

| ID. | Name. | Info. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | JohnDoe | Info about the individual, extra info... |
| 12346 | JaneDoe | Info about the individual. |
| 12347 | JohnSmith | Info about the individual. |

So far I've been able to filter the first frame to create columns of IDs and Names, but how can I group separate infos into one string to create a column with the same number of rows as the other two?

Comment: Please include the original data and not the structure of your dataframe. Do you have spaces??

Comment: Also isnt row 4 a repetition of row 3?

Comment: Which of the two do you have? The first one or the second one? Is the fist one in a file?

Comment: I have the first and it's just a text file.

Comment: check the edit for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Using `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(person = cumsum(Column_1 == 'ID.')) %>%
  pivot_wider(person, names_from = Column_1, values_from = Column_2)

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  person ID.   Name. Info 
   <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1      1 ID#   Name  Info 
2      2 ID#   Name  Info 
3      3 ID#   Name  Info
```

EDIT:

If you have a text file just do

```
a <- readLines('file.txt')
read.dcf(textConnection(gsub("(?m)^(\\w+) ", '\\1:', a, perl = TRUE)), all=TRUE)
     ID      NAME                                                       INFO
1 12345   JohnDoe Info about the individual, Extra info about the individual
2 12346   JaneDoe                                  Info about the individual
3 12347 JohnSmith                                  Info about the individual
```

where the `file.txt` looks like given in the question.

With the updated `df` you could do:

```
df %>%
   filter(Column.1!='') %>%
   group_by(grp = cumsum(Column.1=='ID.'), name=Column.1) %>%
   summarise(value = toString(Column.2), .groups = 'drop') %>%
   pivot_wider(grp)

# A tibble: 3 x 4
    grp ID.   Info                                                       Name.    
  <int> <chr> <chr>                                                      <chr>    
1     1 12345 Info about the individual, Extra info about the individual JohnDoe  
2     2 12346 Info about the individual                                  JaneDoe  
3     3 12347 Info about the individual.                                 JohnSmith
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  filter_all(any_vars(.!="")) %>% 
  group_by(Column1) %>% 
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Column1, values_from = Column2, values_fn = list) %>% 
  unnest(cols = c(ID., Name., Info)) %>% 
  select(-row)
```

```
 ID.   Name.     Info                           
  <chr> <chr>     <chr>                          
1 12345 JohnDoe   Info about the individual      
2 12346 JaneDoe   Extra info about the individual
3 12347 JohnSmith Info about the individual      
4 NA    NA        Info about the individual.
```